# Не появляется второе модальное окно

Tags: javascript, html, css

При нажатие на копку APPLY должно пропадать первое модальное окно и появляться второе. Но этого не происходит

```js
const popupSubscribe = document.querySelector('#popupSubscribe');
const popupSubscribeCurtain = document.querySelector('#popupSubscribeCurtain');
const popupSubscribeWrapper = document.querySelector('#popupSubscribeWrapper');
const popupPaymentWrapper = document.querySelector('#popupPaymentWrapper');
const popupSubscribeButton = document.querySelector('#popupSubscribeButton');
const popupSubscribeButtonApply = document.querySelector('#popupSubscribeButtonApply');
const popupSubscribeClose = document.querySelector('#popupSubscribeClose');

popupSubscribeButton.addEventListener('click',function () {
    popupSubscribe.classList.add('active')
    popupSubscribeWrapper.classList.add('active')
    body.classList.add('noscroll')
});

popupSubscribeClose.addEventListener('click',function () {
    popupSubscribe.classList.remove('active')
    popupSubscribeWrapper.classList.remove('active')
    body.classList.remove('noscroll')
});

popupSubscribeCurtain.addEventListener('click',function () {
    popupSubscribe.classList.remove('active')
    popupSubscribeWrapper.classList.remove('active')
    body.classList.remove('noscroll')
});

popupSubscribeButtonApply.addEventListener('click',function () {
    popupSubscribeWrapper.classList.remove('active')
    popupPaymentWrapper.classList.add('active')
});
```

```css
.benefit__button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 207px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 54px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: "Gotham Pro Bold", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 130%;
  color: #171717;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
.popup-subscribe {
  max-width: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.popup-subscribe.active {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  transition: all ease-in 0.8s;
}

.popup-subscribe.active .popup-subscribe__curtain {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.popup-subscribe__wrapper.active {
  left: 0;
}

.popup-subscribe__curtain,
.popup-payment__curtain {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #e5e5e594;
  z-index: 3;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.popup-subscribe__wrapper {
  max-width: 540px;
  max-height: 581px;
}

.popup-subscribe__wrapper,
.popup-payment__wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 24px rgba(213, 216, 221, 0.2);
  border-radius: 32px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 40px 0 40px 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 13%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 200%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 4;
  transition: left ease-in-out 0.8s;
}

.popup-subscribe__inner {
  max-width: 460px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.popup-subscribe__block {
  max-width: 460px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.popup-subscribe__title {
  font-family: "Gotham Pro Regular", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 140%;
  color: #171717;
}

.popup-subscribe__close {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background: rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.1);
  border-radius: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popup-subscribe__svg-tablet {
  display: none;
}

.popup-subscribe__form,
.popup-subscribe__box {
  max-width: 460px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto 32px;
  position: relative;
}

.popup-subscribe__box_last {
  margin: 0;
}

.popup-subscribe__label,
.popup-payment__label-wallet {
  font-family: "Gotham Pro Regular", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 130%;
  color: #171717;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
}

.popup-subscribe__input,
.popup-payment__input-wallet {
  max-width: 460px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #F1F4F8;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 16px 0 16px 24px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  font-family: "Gotham Pro Regular", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 130%;
  color: #070033;
}

.popup-subscribe__input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-family: "Gotham Pro Regular", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 130%;
  color: #8F8F8F;
}

.popup-subscribe__input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-family: "Gotham Pro Regular", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 130%;
  color: #8F8F8F;
}

.popup-subscribe__input::-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-family: "Gotham Pro Regular", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 130%;
  color: #8F8F8F;
}

.popup-subscribe__input::placeholder {
  font-family: "Gotham Pro Regular", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 130%;
  color: #8F8F8F;
}

.popup-subscribe__input:hover {
  border: 2px solid #838099;
}

.popup-subscribe__input:focus {
  border: 2px solid #CECBDF;
  outline: none;
}

.popup-subscribe__input:valid {
  border: 2px solid #1749B3;
}

.popup-subscribe__input:active {
  border: 2px solid #CECBDF;
  outline: none;
}

.popup-subscribe__span::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 17px;
  transition: all ease-in 0.3s;
  transform: scale(0);
}

.popup-subscribe__input:valid + .popup-subscribe__span::after {
  content: "+";
  transform: scale(1);
}

.popup-subscribe__input:valid:not(:focus) {
  border: transparent;
}

.popup-subscribe__input:valid:not(:focus) + .popup-subscribe__span::after {
  content: "+";
}

.popup-subscribe__button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #1749B3;
  max-width: 460px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 54px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "Gotham Pro Bold", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 130%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.popup-subscribe__button:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #1749B3;
  color: #171717;
}

.popup-subscribe__button:active {
  background-color: #4B84FD;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.popup-payment__wrapper {
  max-width: 580px;
  max-height: 869px;
  top: 4%;
  transform: scale(0);
}

.popup-payment__wrapper.active {
  left: 0;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.popup-payment__inner {
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.popup-payment__block {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 33px;
}

.popup-payment__close {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.popup-payment__services {
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.popup-payment__apple,
.popup-payment__google {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  max-width: 240px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 54px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.popup-payment__card,
.popup-payment__box,
.popup-payment__wallet {
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.popup-payment__card {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.popup-payment__box {
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.popup-payment__label,
.popup-payment__label-wallet {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.popup-payment__input {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.popup-payment__wrapper-form {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.popup-payment__box-form {
  max-width: 240px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.popup-payment__button {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.popup-payment__button-card {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.popup-payment__privacy {
  font-family: "Gotham Pro Regular", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 130%;
  color: #7F7F7F;
}

.popup-payment__subtitle {
  font-family: "Gotham Pro Bold", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 140%;
  color: #171717;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.popup-payment__input-wallet {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.popup-payment__box-wallet {
  position: relative;
}

.popup-payment__box-wallet::after {
  content: "+";
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  right: 27px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
 <button class="benefit__button" id="popupSubscribeButton">Start using</button>


<!--    Subscription Application-->
    <div class="popup-subscribe" id="popupSubscribe">
        <div class="popup-subscribe__curtain" id="popupSubscribeCurtain"></div>
        <div class="popup-subscribe__wrapper" id="popupSubscribeWrapper">
            <div class="popup-subscribe__inner">
                <div class="popup-subscribe__block">
                    <div class="popup-subscribe__title">Subscription Application</div>
                    <div class="popup-subscribe__close" id="popupSubscribeClose">
                        <img class="popup-subscribe__svg" src="home/image/close.svg" alt="close">
                        <img class="popup-subscribe__svg-tablet" src="home/image/close-tablet.svg" alt="close">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <form class="popup-subscribe__form">
                    <div class="popup-subscribe__box popup-subscribe__box-name">
                        <label class="popup-subscribe__label" for="popup-subscribe__name">Enter your name</label>
                        <input class="popup-subscribe__input" id="popup-subscribe__name" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Anastasiia" required>
                        <span class="popup-subscribe__span"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="popup-subscribe__box">
                        <label class="popup-subscribe__label" for="popup-subscribe__mail">E-mail</label>
                        <input class="popup-subscribe__input" id="popup-subscribe__mail" type="email" name="E-mail" placeholder="Enter your e-mail" required>
                        <span class="popup-subscribe__span"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="popup-subscribe__box popup-subscribe__box_last">
                        <label class="popup-subscribe__label" for="popup-subscribe__phone">Phone</label>
                        <input class="popup-subscribe__input" id="popup-subscribe__phone" type="tel" name="Phone" placeholder="Enter your phone" required>
                        <span class="popup-subscribe__span"></span>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <button class="popup-subscribe__button" id="popupSubscribeButtonApply">Apply</button>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!--    Purchase payment-->
        <div class="popup-payment__wrapper" id=popupPaymentWrapper">
            <div class="popup-payment__inner">
                <div class="popup-payment__block popup-subscribe__block">
                    <div class="popup-payment__title popup-subscribe__title">Purchase payment</div>
                    <div class="popup-payment__close popup-subscribe__close">
                        <img class="popup-subscribe__svg" src="home/image/close.svg" alt="close">
                        <img class="popup-subscribe__svg-tablet" src="home/image/close-tablet.svg" alt="close">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="popup-payment__services">
                    <div class="popup-payment__apple">
                        <img src="home/image/apple.svg" alt="apple">
                    </div>
                    <div class="popup-payment__google">
                        <img src="home/image/google.svg" alt="google">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="popup-payment__card">
                    <div class="popup-payment__box">
                        <label class="popup-payment__label popup-subscribe__label" for="popup-payment__name">Card Number</label>
                        <input class="popup-payment__input popup-subscribe__input" id="popup-payment__name" type="number" name="Card Number" placeholder="1234 1234 1234 1234" required>
                        <span class="popup-payment__span popup-subscribe__span"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="popup-payment__wrapper-form">
                        <div class="popup-payment__box popup-payment__box-form">
                            <label class="popup-payment__label popup-subscribe__label" for="popup-payment__date">Expiration Date</label>
                            <input class="popup-payment__input popup-subscribe__input" id="popup-payment__date" type="number" name="Expiration Date" placeholder="MM/ГГ" required>
                            <span class="popup-payment__span popup-subscribe__span"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="popup-payment__box popup-payment__box-form">
                            <label class="popup-payment__label popup-subscribe__label" for="popup-payment__cvc">СVC</label>
                            <input class="popup-payment__input popup-subscribe__input" id="popup-payment__cvc" type="number" name="СVC" placeholder="СVC" required>
                            <span class="popup-payment__span popup-subscribe__span"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="popup-payment__button popup-payment__button-card popup-subscribe__button">Pay with card</button>
                    <div class="popup-payment__privacy">We do not collect information on your cards, everything is safe</div>
                </div>
                <div class="popup-payment__wallet">
                    <div class="popup-payment__subtitle">Payment by crypto wallet</div>
                    <div class="popup-payment__box popup-payment__box-wallet">
                        <label class="popup-payment__label-wallet" for="popup-payment__crypto">Select currency</label>
                        <input class="popup-payment__input-wallet" id="popup-payment__crypto" type="text" name="Currency" placeholder="Bitcoin" required>
                    </div>
                    <button class="popup-payment__button popup-subscribe__button">Pay</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `document.body` вместо `body`, ну и то, что Вам посоветовали в ответе - в момент инициализации переменных они могут ещё не присутствовать в DOM.

Answer (score 0):

html DOM ещё не успел отрисоваться к моменту, когда идёт обращение в коде. Надо объявить переменные, а после отрисовки их инициализировать

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    ... тут инициализация переменных (не путать с объявлением)
});
```

---

И вместо `body` надо `document.body`

Comment: я не очень понял что надо сделать так-как только недавно начал изучать JS

Comment: Я написал что нужно сделать. Где либо просто **объявить** переменные, а в функции - **инициализировать** (то есть присвоить значения)